# ActionController::UnknownFormat in DashboardApp::DashboardPageController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-rewriting, missing-template

I'm in the process of a URL rename and had all of the routes working but received a suggestion to go back through and update some additional names and now I am running into this error. I have `show.html.erb` in `app/views/dashboard/dashboard_page`.

I have been stuck on this for far too long, messing with file names, but I can't get past it. Any guidance would be great!

Full error message: DashboardApp::DashboardPageController#show is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.

Comment: The full error message should give more context about where rails is looking for the template, and also in what format it is expecting the template. Can you try to add more context to your question? It would also be useful to know you rails version etc.

Possibly rails is looking in `app/views/dashboard_app/dashboard_page`, but I am just guessing.

Comment: Full error message: DashboardApp::DashboardPageController#show is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot. @trueunlessfalse

Answer (score 1):

The solution: I had a typo in a file name *and* I needed to restart my *webpack* server. I had been restarting my rails server but didn't think to do webpack. Hopefully this saves someone else hours of head banging :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're namespacing your controller or doing additional configuration, your folder structure should match your controller name.

So `show.html.erb` should be inside the `app/views/dashboard_page` folder.

OBS:

if `DashboardApp` is a namespace, then `show.html.erb` should be inside `app/views/dashboard_app/dashboard_page`

Comment: I moved `show.html.erb` inside `app/views/dashboard_page` folder but still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you update the post with the code of your controller? if `DashboardApp` is a namespace, then `show.html.erb` should be inside `app/views/dashboard_app/dashboard_page`

Comment: I renamed the folder to `app/views/dashboard_app/dashboard_page` and now get a template missing error: `Missing template layouts/dashboard with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby]}. Searched in: * ".../app/views" *` The file in layouts is titled `dashboard_app.html.erb` but looks like its searching for `dashboard.html.erb`. If I change the file name to that, I get various errors that modules and components are not found